# modifying a WordPress header, but I'm not sure what theme I'm using

Tags: php, wordpress

Even though I'm a programmer (in Python and C++) I hired a guy to do my Wordpress website. I didn't want to spend a lot of time learning Wordpress and he had better graphic design skills. However, I need to make some changes to the header now, and I'm going to try to do them myself to save money.

My first confusion is how my theme is set up. I think the guy I hired based my theme on Roots, but there seems to be a lot of differences between what I see in my website and how Roots is described in some tutorials I found on the web. I thought I would start here by posting some of the code in head.php, header.php, header-top-navbar.php, and page-header.php. My question is---where do I need to make changes in order to add some text to the header? (I want to add a slogan--"Pure Sound for Perceptive Ears")

I know all this may be complicated, so if there is no simple answer, I would like some guidance about understanding what theme is employed here, and how I can learn more about using it. So basically, WHAT IS GOING ON HERE? HELP!

Here is header.php:

```
<header class="banner" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">Brilliant Zen Audio</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-3">
        <nav role="navigation" class="clearfix">
          <?php
            if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
              wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => ''));
            endif;
          ?>
        </nav>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is head.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <?php wp_head(); ?>

  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?> Feed" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/feed/">
</head>
```

Here is header-top-navbar.php:

```
<header class="banner navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <?php
        if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
          wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'));
        endif;
      ?>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

And finally here is page-header.php:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <?php echo roots_title(); ?>
  </h1>
</div>
```

EDIT: here is some code from front-page.php. I see where it puts the slider. What I'm trying to figure out is how it decides where to draw the slider, and also where the brown rectangle comes from.

```
<div class="row">

<?php putRevSlider( "brilliant-zen" ) ?>

</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom:3em;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <h3> Brilliant Zen Audio</h3>
      <p>A Zen master brings all the factors of enlightenment into balance. Brilliant Zen Audio offers a synergistic blend
         of musicality, detail, and dynamics for bringing musical enjoyment into a most pleasureful balance.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <h3>Musicality, Detail, and Dynamics</h3>
      <p>Brilliant Zen Audio is dedicated to providing equipment that excels in musical engagement and beauty, while providing high resolution at the same time.</p><br/>
      <a href="contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-orange">Contact Us</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [roots](https://github.com/roots/roots) theme loads the templates in this order (see `base.php`):

1. `head.php`
2. `header-top-navbar.php` if Bootstrap's navbar is enabled in config.php, otherwise loads `header.php`
3. `page-header.php`, called only when viewing a page (`page.php`)

I'm not sure if you have enabled the Bootstrap navbar so my best guess is to change `header.php`:

```
<header class="banner" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">Brilliant Zen Audio</a></h1>
        <p>"Pure Sound for Perceptive Ears"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-3">
        <nav role="navigation" class="clearfix">
          <?php
            if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
              wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => ''));
            endif;
          ?>
        </nav>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here I added your slogan right below the logo (line 6). HTH

Comment: That's a start, but it crams the text into the same space as my logo image. I tried moving the text to inside the `<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-3">` and then it moves it to above the navigation menu, but pushes the navigation menu down to where it partially disappears. Any ideas? What do all those classes mean (col-xs-12, etc.)

Comment: These are the grid CSS classes. See http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ to understand them. You probably need to change a few CSS classes in your header to get the layout you want.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the slogan in a better position, but the problem now is this. As the guy programmed it, the front page includes the logo and nav menu over on a brown rectangle. Below that rectangle is a Slider. I can move the elements in the header around now, but the size of the brown rectangle doesn't change, and the Slider stays in the same place, so the elements of the header end up getting drawn below the brown rectangle. Do you have any sense where the size of that brown rectangle is defined, and how, perhaps, I could make it automatically enlarge as the header enlarges?

Comment: I edited the question to add code from front-page.php. This may provide some hint as to how the front page is formatted.

Comment: The height of the header is most likely defined via CSS, probably in `style.css`. See if there is a `.banner{ ... }` class and change that accordingly to your needs.

Comment: I found an entry in app.css, referring to header.banner and giving the height as 113px. Something I don't understand is that this appeared inside a "media query" section, `@media (min-width: 768px) { <entries go here> }` Under what conditions is it actually reading the css stating a height of 113 px? Under what conditions is it ignoring that css?

Comment: Those CSS declarations will get parsed if the browser's viewport width >= 768px (try resize your browser). Note: if your original question has been solved please accept/mark the answer. If you have more issues please ask a new question.